# Strip everything after list of possible delimiters without regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of possible delimiters. I am processing a few thousand strings and need to strip everything after one of the delimiters is found. Note: There will never be a case when more than 1 delimiter is in the string.

Example:

```
patterns = ['abc', 'def']
example_string = 'hello world abc 123'
```

If `example_string` is the input in this case, the output should be `hello world abc`.

I am currently using regex for the solution, which is working, but I would like to use an approach that doesn't use regex. Here's my current implementation:

```
 regex = r'(.*)(' + '|'.join(patterns) + r')(.*)'
 example_string= re.sub(regex, r'\1\2', example_string).lstrip()
```

I am thinking something along the lines of searching to see if one of the delimiters from patterns is in the string and then indexing the string from the position of the length of the delimiter until the end of the string.

Don't know exactly if that would be a good way to implement that, or if that would work.

Comment: Roughly how many strings are in `patterns`? Are they all the same length?

Comment: There are 28 strings in patterns, but that is subject to change over time. And no, the lengths of the strings vary.

Comment: In that case, your regex-based approach is probably going to be better than any non-regex solution.

Comment: Your solution doesn't find the first delimiter and strips after that - your solution finds the last delimiter in text, and I'm not sure if that's what you want. Just change 'def' in patterns to '123' and you'll see.

Comment: Sorry if I contradicted myself with anything. My current solution is functioning the way i'd like it to. I am just interested in a non regex approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [find](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) function. Here each pattern is checked and if found the string is sliced at the start location of the pattern (or the end location of the pattern by adding the length of the pattern, as in the example):

```
    patterns = ['abc', 'def']
    example_string = 'hello world abc 123'
    for pattern in patterns:
        location = example_string.find(pattern)
        if location >= 0:
            example_string = example_string[:location + len(pattern)]
            print example_string
            break
```

Answer (score 3):

You can abuse list comprehension and slicing:

```
delimiters = ['a', 'b']
s = 'nvcakl'
s = [s[:s.index(i) + 1] for i in delimiters if i in s]
print(s)
>> ['nvca']
```

This will work even if more than one delimiter is found, each index in the output list will correspond to the found delimiter, eg:

```
delimiters = ['a', 'b']
s = 'nvcaklbh'
s = [s[:s.index(i) + 1] for i in delimiters if i in s]
print(s)
>> ['nvca', 'nvcaklb']
```

Comment: If by some freak chance that there is more than 1 delimiter found, I would want the string to be stripped by the first occurrence of a delimiter. Would this still be an ideal solution?

Comment: The OP's delimiters are strings of varying length, so that `+ 1` won't generally work. Also, this algorithm tests all delimiters even after it's found a match.

Comment: @PM2Ring This is a rough idea, there's no problem to change `+ 1` to `+ len(i)`

Comment: If there's no more than one delimiter in the text it looks like ideal solution. Just put [s[:s.index(i) + 1] for i in delimiters if i in s][0] to return the first (and only one) element. If you want to make it faster you can put a break, as @PM2Ring suggested that algorithm doesn't stop after match. So you can do: 
for i in delimiters:
    if i in s:
        s[:s.index(i) + len(i)]
        break

Answer (score 2):

using the find methode

> string.find(s, sub[, start[, end]])

Return the lowest index in s where the substring sub is found such that sub is wholly contained in s[start:end]. Return -1 on failure. Defaults for start and end and interpretation of negative values is the same as for slices.

and your result is s[:end]